# CGContextRef unit conversion

Tags: ios, cgcontext, cgrectmake

Some month ago I created a PDF Creator using FPDF (PHP Class). Now I was using NSData to fetch the PDF data from a URL into a UIWebView.
Because I'm implementing offline functionalities into my app I want to convert the FPDF PHP Script into cocoa touch.

The unit used in my PHP script is mm. Now I want to know how I can convert mm to the unit used in CGRectMake() (I think it is pixels, am I right?).

Thanks for help, with kind regards, Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, simple math will get you the answer.  Look up the PPI of a *non-retina display*, divide that by 25.4 (mm per inch) and you have your answer in *pixels*.  However, non-retina is 1 pixel per point, so your answer in *points* will be the same (can be used on retina and non-retina both, retina is simply 4 pixels per point but that is taken care of for you).  I'm almost sure this will be different between iPhone and iPad, so you will need to account for both.